# What can I do about "cpio: read error while unpacking archive"?

Tags: linux, rpm

I get the following error when I attempt to install a `.rpm` file:

> error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/local/jive/opt/openoffice.org/basis3.2/program/libicudata.so.40;4d805c75: cpio: read

What could be causing it, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's truncated or corrupted, and the solution is to re-download it.  Yes, I know, painful.  If you're lucky, though, you may be able to use `wget --continue` to pick up from where it chopped off.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while trying to upgrade bash through rpm -Uvh on my RHEL 4. Then i reboot the system. The server did not come up but ask me to repair file system through fsck. I run the fsck and rebooted the system. It resolved my issue.